# MVC CheckboxFor

Tags: model-view-controller, view, checkboxfor

Im trying to make checkbox for each model element in my view. However my lamda expression does not work when trying call my properties. However it does work when using Html.DisplayNameFor.

[image]

I have been trying for several days. Can anyone please point me in the right direction?

BR

Answer (score 1):

```
public class ModtagerOmradeView
{
    [DisplayName("Navan")]
    public bool Navan{ get; set; }
}

public ActionResult IndexUdbetaling()
{
  var modtagerOmradeView= new List<ModtagerOmradeView>()
  return View(modtagerOmradeView);
}

@model IEnumerable<ModtagerOmradeView>
 
@for( int i = 0; i < Model.ModtagerOmradeView.Count(); i++)
{
      @Html.LabelFor(model => modelModtagerOmradeVie[i].Navan)  
      @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => modelModtagerOmradeVie[i].Navan) 
}
```